# Rest API report type object relation

Tags: apex, rest-api, custom-report-type, reports-api

I tried to retrieve report type object relation from rest api. I have checked almost all documentations about this but could find anything about it. Could you please help me if you know a way to get that information.

To clarify my requirement; I need to find base object and other related object and their relation type from either custom or standard report type.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found this but couldnt figure out how to use.
Maybe someone can help me how to use following code block. I guess I need to work on soap 2006 metadata service provider. (http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata)

```
public class ReportType extends Metadata {
    public String type = 'ReportType';
    public String fullName;
    public Boolean autogenerated;
    public String baseObject;
    public String category;
    public Boolean deployed;
    public String description;
    public MetadataService.ObjectRelationship join_x;
    public String label;
    public MetadataService.ReportLayoutSection[] sections;
    private String[] autogenerated_type_info = new String[]{'autogenerated','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] baseObject_type_info = new String[]{'baseObject','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'1','1','false'};
    private String[] category_type_info = new String[]{'category','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'1','1','false'};
    private String[] deployed_type_info = new String[]{'deployed','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'1','1','false'};
    private String[] description_type_info = new String[]{'description','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] join_x_type_info = new String[]{'join','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] label_type_info = new String[]{'label','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'1','1','false'};
    private String[] sections_type_info = new String[]{'sections','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','-1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','true','false'};
    private String[] type_att_info = new String[]{'xsi:type'};
    private String[] fullName_type_info = new String[]{'fullName','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'fullName', 'autogenerated','baseObject','category','deployed','description','join_x','label','sections'};
}
```